# latin bases language segmentation gramatical rules

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp

I am working on one feature i.e. to apply language segmentation rules (grammatical) for Latin based language (English currently).

Currently I am in phase of breaking sentences of user input.

```
e.g.:

"I am working in language translation". "I have used Google MT API for this"
```

In above example i will break above sentence by full stop `.` This is normal cases where I am breaking sentence on dot, but there are n number of characters for breaking sentence like (`.` `!` `?`, etc).

I have following SRX rules for segmentation.

**Is there any reference** which I can use for resolving my language segmentation rules?

Comment: Your tags didn't really make sense, I've changed it to something that (I think) is a little better... it's about natural languages, but *programming* language agnostic :)

Comment: Hey thanks for replying quickly :)
yes...exactly it's natural language not a programming languages..

I already followed http://www.lisa.org/fileadmin/standards/srx20.html#refTR29 (SRX rules ) but I am not interacting with those guys...suggest me other links or forum so that i can interact efficiently...thanks

Comment: Well as English is mostly based on a Saxon dialect from the Dark Ages. The grammer is a pretty unique mix of old german, norse with a smattering of medieval French. There are lots of words stolen from Latin but aside from the odd quirk (Datum as singular for Data) there is almost no Latin based grammer in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at Reynar and Ratnaparkhi's paper [**A Maximum Entropy Approach to Identifying Sentence Boundaries**](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/acl/A/A97/A97-1004.pdf) (1997).

**Abstract**

> We present a trainable model for identifying
> sentence boundaries in raw text. Given
> a corpus annotated with sentence boundaries,
> our model learns to classify each occurrence
> of., ?, and / as either a valid or invalid
> sentence boundary. The training procedure
> requires no hand-crafted rules, lexica,
> part-of-speech tags, or domain-specific
> information. The model can therefore be
> trained easily on any genre of English, and
> should be trainable on any other Romanalphabet
> language. Performance is comparable
> to or better than the performance of
> similar systems, but we emphasize the simplicity
> of retraining for new domains.

Their resulting sentence segmenter is known as **MxTerminator** and is available [here](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/adwait/jmx/).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a good amount of literature about this in linguistics journals...

This is a nice report about the problem, hope it can help you 
http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1068&context=ircs_reports

nico